# Help me find the source of this item in my $PATH

Tags: bash, .profile

When I start a new shell, I end up with the following $PATH:

`/home/ldt/.local/bin:`**/home/ldt/bin**`:/home/ldt/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper/shims:/home/ldt/.pyenv/libexec:/home/ldt/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin:/home/ldt/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper/bin:/home/ldt/.pyenv/shims:/home/ldt/.pyenv/bin:`**/home/ldt/bin**`:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin`

Now, there's clearly something not quite right there. I don't really expect it to cause many problems, but it could be a sign of a more serious configuration error. So I'd like to understand what happened and if it needs fixing.

But I cannot find the source of that second copy of /home/ldt/bin!

What I have tried:

```
$ unset PATH
$ source /etc/environment
$ source /etc/profile
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin
```

This is nice information because we have clearly reached the point where the next event should add the entry I want to find.

Except that as far as I know and the internet tells me, the next source file is my own .profile:

```
$ source ~/.profile
$ echo $PATH
/home/ldt/.local/bin:/home/ldt/bin:/home/ldt/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper/shims:/home/ldt/.pyenv/libexec:/home/ldt/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin:/home/ldt/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper/bin:/home/ldt/.pyenv/shims:/home/ldt/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin
```

And it's not there! This is exactly the $PATH I want to have.

So something gets sourced, something happens somewhere between /etc/profile and ~/.profile...

Does anyone have a clue what that might be?

Comment: can try `grep -IRni '/home/ldt/bin' ~ /etc`

Comment: There's one thing that really drew my eye there: `/home/ldt/.xsession-errors:49:dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/home/ldt/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin`

Comment: `grep -IRni '$HOME/bin' ~ /etc` or `grep -IRni '~/bin' ~ /etc`

Comment: ...you `~/.profile` says if `$HOME/bin` exists add it.

Comment: @bac0n I know that and that is the source of the instance that's at the front of the list. I would prefer to keep that as it allows me to make personal overrides. I'm trying to find the source of the other copy of it...

Comment: put `set +x` in your /etc/profile and login